# Python: Integrate the number of columns into a variable

Tags: python

I am new to python and could need your help.

I have the variable 'sequence' which shows the optimal order of products.

```
sequence = seq_2
```

with for example:

```
 seq_2 = [[0, 0], [1, 0]] 
 seq_4 = [[0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1, 0]]
```

What I want to do is to change the '2' according to the number of columns of a matrix I have generated.
For example, if the matrix has 6 columns (= 6 products), the variable should be:

```
  sequence = seq_6
```

I know that the number of columns can be generated with:

```
columns = len(df.columns)
```

But how to combine the result to  my "sequence"-varible?

Best regards
Amy

Comment: what is seq_2 and seq_6, assuming that they are also variables, and probably arrays right? Please proivde more information.

Comment: Yes, thats true. I tried to make it clearer

Answer (score 0):

is this the answer you are looking for?

```
sequence = 'seq_' + str(len(df.columns))
```

With the string function seq_ can be concatenated to the number columns in the df